# CFFILE attribution error with action="rename", says the file is invalid

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfc, cffile

My page has a form on it that interacts with a CFC via an ajax post. When the user changes the text and clicks save it should update the DB, which it does, and rename a photo with the value they typed in. Everything works except that I keep getting the error:

`The value of the attribute source, which is currently /Applications/ColdFusion8/wwwroot/theClient/staging/admin/images/Old_Image.jpg, is invalid.`

The file exists and I've changed it to read/write for everyone but ti still gives me the error.

Any ideas?

I should point out that a var in my CFC runs a replace for spaces and changes them out for underscores so, there's no spaces in the filename...

Comment: Can you show exact coding and error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember right this is probably a problem with the *destination* file name rather then the source filename.  I think it's a bug with the error message in CF.

Comment: See here:  http://www.1pixelout.net/2005/06/23/an-incredibly-usefull-cffile-error-message/

Comment: For the record - I have filed a bug on this in the past so hopefully it will be corrected in a future version of CF.

Comment: BINGO! It was the destination that was the trouble, not the source. I looked back over my variable that defined the path for the destination I realized I had omitted the expandPath()... Thank you, Todd.

Comment: Not sure if this is still a bug in the current version, but it still exists in CF9

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are using a relative path to the source file.  The problem is, relative links in the source attribute are relative to the ColdFusion temporary directory.  Try giving an absolute path or using the EXPANDPATH function to create an absolute path to your resource like this:

```
<cffile action="rename" source="#expandPath('/Applications/ColdFusion8/wwwroot/theClient/staging/admin/images/Old_Image.jpg')#" destination="#expandPath('/Applications/ColdFusion8/wwwroot/theClient/staging/admin/images/NEW_Image.jpg')#">
```

From the CF 9 documentation on CFFILE action="rename"

> If not an absolute path (starting with a drive letter and a colon, or a forward or backward slash), it is relative to the ColdFusion temporary directory, which is returned by the GetTempDirectory function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in the end it was something else: the ColdFusion user had no "modify" permission in the folder. It had read/write but not modify. (sigh!)